# Java Serial port Read and Write

Tags: java

COM3 and COM4 are connected to each other using loop.
This is my code:

```
import jssc.*;

public class ReadingPorts {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SerialPortTimeoutException {
        SerialPort serialPortW = new SerialPort("COM3");
        SerialPort serialPortR = new SerialPort("COM4");
        try {
            serialPortW.openPort();
            serialPortR.openPort();

            serialPortW.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_9600,
                    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            serialPortR.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_9600,
                    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            serialPortW.writeBytes("test".getBytes());

            byte[] buffer=serialPortR.readBytes(10);
            System.out.println(buffer);

    ....
```

But when I compile and run it, it takes too much(infinite time) to read the data from COM4 whereas writing data to COM3 takes seconds.

Why?

Comment: `readBytes` is probably a blocking call that does not return until there is some actual data to be read

Comment: When i use PUTTY and open com3 in putty, I type random data in com3 window in putty while running the above program it returns some garbage value [B@14ae5a5.

Comment: "garbage" may come from putty interpreting the data as ascii (you send exactly 8 bits = 1 byte = 1 ascii symbol :D)

Comment: So if i do not use putty, and use the above program for loopback testing of the two ports for I/O, what should I change?

Comment: `[B@14ae5a5` is not a garbage, it is result of `toString()` for `buffer`  .
 Use `Arrays.toString(buffer)` to see content of buffer. [See java class naming for arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29)